# myComboBox->Dismiss(); not working under wxEVT_TEXT and wxEVT_COMBOBOX_DROPDOWN

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

My objective:
During wxEVT_COMBOBOX_DROPDOWN load up a choiceDialog and set the choice as combo box value and finally close the combobox using dismiss().

What I  tried:

```
void Class_Scheduler_FNFrame::myComboBoxDropdown(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    
    SingleChoiceDialog1->ShowModal();
    int i = SingleChoiceDialog1->GetSelection();

    myComboBox->SetValue(wxString::Format(("%s"), myWxStringArray[i]));
    myComboBox->Dismiss();
}
```

The value got changed but the dismiss(); is not working.
So I tried moving dismiss to wxEVT_TEXT.

```
void Class_Scheduler_FNFrame::myComboBoxTextUpdated(wxCommandEvent& event)
{
    testLabel->SetLabel("This should have worked");
    myComboBox->Dismiss();
}
```

Dismiss() is not working in wxEVT_TEXT as well. But when I type onto the combobox, after triggering wxEVT_COMBOBOX_DROPDOWN,  dismiss() is working through wxEVT_TEXT .

Help!

Comment: can you describe in plain English what flow you are after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to do something rather weird: have you ever seen a modal dialog show while the combobox dropdown is opened? I haven't and, generally speaking, there should be only a single modal element shown at each moment.

So why do you have this objective? What is the point of showing the dialog whenever a combobox is opened? It doesn't even seem like you're using it like a combobox at all. Maybe you're actually after some kind of `wxFilePickerCtrl`-like behaviour, i.e. a small button showing the dialog near a text control? Or maybe you want to use `wxComboCtrl` instead?

Anyhow, it should be possible to do what you want by postponing showing the dialog using `CallAfter()`, but I'm almost sure that you actually don't want to do that anyhow.